# streaming speed for video content on iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, video-streaming

My application was rejected from Apple today.Apple says that the video stream should be not more than at 64kbps.

what should i will have to do get my application approve on App Store?? Should i have to make changes on video content that i am streaming from my iPhone or should i have to change in code?

Please suggest.

Thanks,

Jim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to re-encode your video so that it has an average bitrate of at most 64 Kbps. Tools such as mencoder and ffmpeg might help you with this.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Let me have to try with this.